# removing duplicates from list of strings (output from Twilio call - Ruby)

Tags: ruby, arrays, string, twilio

I'm trying to display total calls from a twilio object as well as unique calls.

The total calls is simple enough:

```
# set up a client to talk to the Twilio REST API
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account

@calls = @subaccount.calls
@total_calls = @calls.list.count
```

However, I'm really struggling to figure out how to display unique calls (people sometimes call back form the same number and I only want to count calls from the same number once).  I'm thinking this is a pretty simple method or two but I've burnt quite a few hours trying to figure it out (still a ruby noob).

Currently I've been working it in the console as follows:

```
@sub_account_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(@account_sid, @auth_token)
@subaccount = @sub_account_client.account

@subaccount.calls.list({})each do |call|
  #"from" returns the phone number that called
  print call.from
end
```

This returns the following strings:

```
+13304833615+13304833615+13304833615+13304833615+13304567890+13304833615+13304833615+13304833615
```

There are only two unique numbers there so I'd like to be able to return '2' for this.

Calling class on that output shows strings.  I've used "insert" to add a space then have done a split(" ") to turn them into arrays but the output is the following:

```
[+13304833615][+13304833615][+13304833615][+13304833615][+13304567890][+13304833615][+13304833615][+13304833615]
```

I can't call 'uniq' on that and I've tried to 'flatten' as well.

Please enlighten me!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have is a string that you want to manipulate the below works:

%{+13304833615+13304833615+13304833615+13304833615+13304567890+13304833615+13304833615+13304833615}.split("+").uniq.reject { |x| x.empty? }.count
    => 2

However this is more ideal:

```
@subaccount.calls.list({}).map(&:from).uniq.count
```

Comment: You got it.  Thank you so much.  I get everything in that line except the (&:from).  I get that map is creating a new array but what are you passing it?  If its a long explanation, can you tell me what you'd call that so I can research it?  I want to make sure I fully understand this.  Thanks again!

Comment: (&:from) is called symbol to proc, ruby takes the :from and converts it to a proc object that is called on every member of the array for better explanation read here http://pragdave.pragprog.com/pragdave/2005/11/symbolto_proc.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you build an array directly instead of converting it into a string first? Try something like this perhaps?

```
@calllist = []
@subaccount.calls.list({})each do |call|
  #"from" returns the phone number that called
  @calllist.push call.from
end
```

you should then be able to call uniq on @calllist to shorten it to the unique members.

Edit: What type of object is @subaccount.calls.list anyway?

Answer (score 0):

`uniq` should work for creating a unique list of strings. I think you may be getting confused by other non-related things. You don't want `.split`, that's for turning a single string into an array of word strings (default splits by spaces). Which has turned each single number string, into an array containing only that number. You may also have been confused by performing your `each` call in the irb console, which will return the full array iterated on, even if your inner loop did the right thing. Try the following:

```
unique_numbers = @subaccount.calls.list({}).map {|call| call.from }.uniq
puts unique_numbers.inspect
```

Comment: this worked as well.  Thank you for your answer!  I'm unsure of protocol regarding which to mark as accepted answer when two work properly and I don't know enough yet to know which is 'best practice' (assuming one is better than the other).  The other was first so I marked that.